# SQL error, after using console, php scripts?

Tags: php, sql

i am trying to make a simple webbsite, and for create a fast database i use the console of it, but after create it i recive an error, and i am not sure why.
the database code for create it is

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `login`.`users` (
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'Llave unica',
  `user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s name, unique',
  `user_password_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Contraseña',
  `user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'Mail',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='user data';
```

after run it on a databse, it creates everything fine, but an error show up, that says:

```
Warning in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#615
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
.\libraries\sql.lib.php#2079: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'login',
string 'users',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `users`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
.\sql.php#219: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'login',
string 'users',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `users`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

someone know why is happening? i am using MAMP for test it

Comment: That error has nothing to do with your database, your counting something with `count()` that is not an array.  There is no way to know what you are counting as it's not present in what you posted.  [For Example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85c36b59462ea9edf218a9019ec0da86506f9a07)

Comment: What you mean? an script is causing this? i tried a global search for count and 0 results

Comment: Why search globally, it tells you right here `Warning in .\libraries\sql.lib.php#615`

Comment: yes, i dont have any script called like that, that is why i am searching .-. so probably is from mamp

Comment: found it was from mamp, i will reinstall it, TY! :D

Comment: Maybe not "you" as in code you created, but rest assured there is some code called that somewhere... lol ... I don't know if just reinstalling it will correct it, you should see what its counting and why it's not an array.  Sometimes you can work back from an error and find out what the actual problem is.  This is probably a symptom of the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

That error has nothing to do with your database, your counting something with `count()` that is not an array.

There is no way to know what you are counting as it's not present in what you posted.

For example this code produces the same exact error:

```
$foo = true;     
count($foo);
```

Here I am trying to use count on a boolean value, which obviously won't work.

Output:

```
<br />
<b>Warning</b>:  count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/85c36b59462ea9edf218a9019ec0da86506f9a07)

Comment: Ty, but i dont have anything on my scripts, maybe is on some mamp scrip ?

Comment: I don't know about that, all I know is that is what that error is for.  Why whatever is doing the counting is counting something other then an array, I have no way to know.